# Case Owner Name null in case of queue

Tags: apex, community, case, queue, case-object

How to remove Case Owner Name as null null when assigning the case to a queue for salesforce communities?
[image: IT looks like this]

The Case Owner is getting properly populated in case of Owner being a User.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Case Assignment Setup under Cases Section.
Check the Default owner's name.